# Text Mining in R: Creating a Corpus creates unusual text

Tags: r, text-mining

I'm reading in a single text file and my code below. It reads in fine but places a \t in random places throughout the corpus.

Examples:
**Original in text file**
5.  If you are responding as an individual,.....
**In Corpus**
"5.\tIf you are responding as an individual,...

or
Q1. What lessons can we learn from elsewhere....
"Q1.\tWhat lessons can we learn from elsewhere.....

It seems like a tab is being translated into a \t in the corpus

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks

```
# set pathway to text files
folder<-"C:\\xxxxxx\\Text files"
folder
# lists all files in pathway 
list.files(path=folder)
# filters text files only
list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.txt")

# set vector
filelist<-list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.txt")

# assign pathways to files
paste(folder, "\\", filelist)
# removes separations in pathways by setting as empty
filelist<-paste(folder, "\\", filelist, sep="")
filelist

# apply a function to read in multiple txt files - warnings are OK
a<-lapply(filelist, FUN=readLines)
# apply a function to collaspe into a single element
corpus<-lapply(a, FUN=paste, collaspe=" ")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The tab characters are in your original file--you just can't see them because TAB is a non-printable character. They're not being "inserted" or "translated"--they're being escaped: \t is the escape sequence for the TAB character.

Comment: Thanks hector, makes it clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gsub()` is a great function that will substitute all instances of a pattern with a different string. For your case, this should help:

```
# apply a function to read in multiple txt files - warnings are OK
a<-lapply(filelist, FUN=readLines)
# apply a function to collaspe into a single element
corpus<-lapply(a, FUN=paste, collaspe=" ")
# replace all '\t' with '   '
corpus<-gsub(pattern = '\\\t', replacement = '', corpus)
```

Comment: Brilliant Thomas, that works a treat. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Thomas, I had to change it subtly to 
corpus<-gsub(pattern = "\\\\t", replacement =  " ", corpus)
to cover off the double \